# Initialize Netlogo world with two breeds; only one turtle per patch

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to set up a world in Netlogo where there are two breeds, but there is only one turtle per patch:

```
breed [supras supra]
breed [subs sub]

turtles-own [age]
subs-own [status]

to setup
  clear-all

  ;; Color the patches so they're easier to see
  ask patches [ set pcolor random-float 2 ]

  ;; num-turtles patches will sprout one turtle each
  ask n-of (num-turtles / 2) patches [
    if not any? turtles-on patch-set self [
      sprout-subs 1
    ]
  ]

  ask n-of (num-turtles / 2) patches [
    if not any? turtles-on patch-set self [
      sprout-supras 1
    ]

  ]

  ;; Set breed colors and own-variables
  ask subs [
    set color blue
    set shape "dot"
  ]

  ask supras [
    set color pink
    set shape "dot"
  ]

  reset-ticks
end

to go

  ask turtles [
    fd 1
  ]

  tick
end
```

This seems to work but I can't quite tell if it's technically correct. What would be a good test to write to make sure I don't have some patches with multiple turtles on initialization?

Comment: I think your code is solid- if you want to confirm you could check by including something like `if any? patches with [ count turtles-here > 1 ] [ setup ]` near the end of your `setup` procedure- this will rerun your setup procedure if there are any patches with more than two `turtles-here`. Obviously, if you later include more turtles in your `setup` then that check will no longer work.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I tried what you suggested then tried ``if any? patches with [ count turtles-here > 1 ] [ output-print "reset" ]`` near the end of my setup method and it didn't seem to print ``reset`` for as long as I waited. Good enough for me.

Comment: Right on. You can also confirm that it works by changing the  `> 1` to `> 0` and watching `setup` run into infinity- but you will have to stop it with Tools > Halt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to strip your code down to what is needed for a complete example.

```
globals [num-turtles]
breed [supras supra]
breed [subs sub]

turtles-own [age]
subs-own [status]

to setup
  clear-all
  set num-turtles 99
  ;; num-turtles patches will sprout one turtle each
  ask n-of (num-turtles / 2) patches [sprout-subs 1] 
  ask n-of (num-turtles / 2) patches with [not any? turtles-here] [
      sprout-supras 1
  ]
end

to test-setup
  if (int (num-turtles / 2) != count supras) [error "setup error: supras"]
  if (int (num-turtles / 2) != count subs) [error "setup error: subs"]
  if any? patches with [count turtles-here > 1] [error "setup error: patches"]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I am actually going to suggest a different approach; instead of randomly selecting some patches for one breed and some patches for the other and trying to avoid each other, you can just select the full number of patches to sprout initially and then convert half your turtles into the other breed.

```
globals [num-turtles]
breed [supras supra]
breed [subs sub]

turtles-own [age]
subs-own [status]

to setup
  clear-all
  set num-turtles 99
  ask n-of num-turtles patches [sprout-subs 1] 
  ask n-of (num-turtles / 2) subs [set breed supras]
  <procedures to set colours etc>
end
```